# Run-time Generation Compilation of CLR

Tags: c#, clr, cil

I have a C# application which generates .NET functions at run-time and executes them.
To do so, it generates C# in strings and calls the online C# compiler to convert it into CLR to be JIT compiled and executed.

For performance reasons, I would like to be able to generate directly CLR (in strings or through an internal representation) and execute it without using any compiler (but perhaps the JIT compiler).

Is that possible ? I've seen some articles about code injection, but that doesn't exactly fits the bill.

Thank you !

Comment: Do you mean generate CIL (aka IL)? It makes no sense to talk about "generating CLR".

Comment: Hum, you are right, I meant CIL of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that [`System.Reflection.Emit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx) is what you're after. In particular, if you only want to generate a single method, I believe you should look at [DynamicMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx). You can ask it to [create an ILGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcbx21sk.aspx), build the IL, and then it will be JIT compiled when you convert the method into a delegate.

I don't believe you can just give it textual IL though... you'll be using the API, explicitly building various instructions. There may be an IL parser which uses this though...

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I took a look at this namspace, and particulary to the ILGenerator which seems to be what I was looking for. I'll look at it in more details, especially regarding the speed.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to create .Net functions, [Expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) are the way to go. If you want to make a whole class, you can use [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx), but then you're writing assembly code.

If you wait for .Net 5, maybe they will have a version of the compiler that you can pass arbitrary C# code to, but for now maybe you can use something that uses the DLR (like IronPython) to pass actual source code to.

Comment: I did not known about expression trees; those are better than the CODEDOM which I used some time ago. But I was looking for a more low-level solution.

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand the question, but couldn't you, instead of generating C# code from your application, actually generate the equivalent intermediate language (IL) code that the C# compiler would generate anyway? Then you could just run the IL code directly without having to compile it first.

Comment: You're right, so my question was about how to do that. Sorry for not being clear enough.